# Reasons why a stored procedure is not found

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I just created a simple stored procedure using `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MYSP`

On my test db I can use it (as `sa` user) by

```
EXEC sp_MYSP
```

But on the production db as I type

```
EXEC sp_MYSP
```

in management studio I see `sp_MYSP` underlined in red.

But I see the sp in Programmability/Stored Procedures tree.

I also tried to run

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_MYSP  TO PUBLIC
```

even being sa user I should not need it.

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried using database and schema to call it also? `EXEC DatabaseName.schema.sp_MYSP`

Comment: yes i tried, i forgot to mention. Thanks

Comment: seeing red squiggly line doesnt mean object doesnt exist, can you actually execute it ?

Comment: No i cannot execute, even if i found a workaround: drop and create seems to work. But still why the problem was there is not clear

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s good to know. Anyway i found the mistery. Simply a stupid mistake. I have two instances with similar name and i was creating objects in the wrong one. So very simple solution even if i lost one full morning. Thanks anyway. I will post an answer since it could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I realized i made a silly error.

I have 2 instances called:

```
.\MyInstance2008R2
```

and

```
.\Instance2008r2
```

so very siumilar names.

I simply created the objects in the first and trying to access them from the second.